# Bootstrap's push and pull classes not working?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Order on small devices:

```
1
2
3
4
```

And on desktop devices is:

```
1
3
2
4
```

**My Code:**

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="sidebar-right" class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
      <h3 class="title">1</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-push-6">
      <h2>2</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar-left" class="col-lg-6  col-sm-6 col-lg-pull-6">
      <h2>3</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar-right" class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
      <h2>4</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your current code?

Comment: I wasn't the downvote btw, but at 2.2k rep you'd think you'd make a snippet? :)

Comment: Bootstrap's `push` and `pull` classes are for horizontal swapping not vertical...

Comment: @Mohammad Usman - Yes I missed that. Renders whole question "impossible".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Bootstrap's `push` and `pull` classes are for horizontal swapping not
>   vertical.

You will need custom styling for this.

### Approach # 01 - Flexbox:

CSS3 [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) can be used to make it. We need to wrap the middle two element (that need to be swapped) in a `div`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem">1</div>
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="elem">2</div>
    <div class="elem">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="elem">4</div>
</div>
```

**Necessary CSS:**

```
.holder {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .holder {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

```css
.container .elem {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

.holder {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .holder {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem">1</div>
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="elem">2</div>
    <div class="elem">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="elem">4</div>
</div>
```

---

### Approach # 02 - Table Properties:

If support in older browsers is also needed then you can use css table properties:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem">1</div>

  <div class="holder">
    <div class="elem">2</div>
    <div class="elem-holder">
      <div class="elem">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="elem">4</div>
</div>
```

**Necessary CSS:**

```
.holder {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .holder .elem-holder {
    display: table-header-group;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1%;
  }
}
```

```css
.container .elem {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

.holder {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .holder .elem-holder {
    display: table-header-group;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem">1</div>
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="elem">2</div>
    <div class="elem-holder">
      <div class="elem">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="elem">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also use [flexbox `order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) instead of changing `flex-direction`.

Comment: @PrzemysławZalewski yes, exactly, that will work too. Its a matter of choice.